# why does the default.vue in layouts of nuxt3 not work

Tags: nuxt3

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>123</p>
            <slot/>
   </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
    .router-link-exact-active{
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

I have checked the path of layouts and pages, but the default.vue doesn't apply it's template to the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code, it's unclear what you're trying to say. However, if I guess correctly, you want to ask why your Nuxt3 app is not using the default layout.

Here are a few solutions:

If you are using app.vue, you need to wrap your  component in the  component like this:

```html
<NuxtLayout name="default">
   <NuxtPage />
</NuxtLayout>

<!-- You can also pass a dynamic name -->

<NuxtLayout :name="name">
   <NuxtPage />
</NuxtLayout>
```

If you are not using app.vue, you need to use the definePageMeta() macro within your pages like this:

```html
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'default'
})
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks, I have been watching videos about how to create a page with nuxt3 and in the one that teach me how to use layouts then this error came out, but finally the I find out that this video dosen't tell me using layout need to install tailwind so the problem is missing module of tailwind.css